# Android : Camera freezes when the flash is turned on

Tags: android, android-camera

I'm working on an app that works with camera but I'm getting an error.
When the camera is active, the camera freezes when the flashlight is turned on or Error **"E/Camera: Error 2"**. Many thanks.

```
 public void FlashOn()
    {
        cam = Camera.open();
        Camera.Parameters params = cam.getParameters();

        if (params.getFlashMode().equals(Camera.Parameters.FLASH_MODE_ON)) 
        {                            
           params.setFlashMode(Camera.Parameters.FLASH_MODE_ON);
        } 
        else 
        {
           params.setFlashMode(Camera.Parameters.FLASH_MODE_OFF);
        }
        cam.setParameters(params);
        cam.startPreview();
    }

   public void FlashOff()
   {
       Camera.Parameters params = cam.getParameters();
       if (params.getFlashMode().equals(Camera.Parameters.FLASH_MODE_ON))
       {
          params.setFlashMode(Camera.Parameters.FLASH_MODE_ON);
       }
       else
       {
          params.setFlashMode(Camera.Parameters.FLASH_MODE_OFF);
       }
          cam.stopPreview();
          cam.release();
    }
```

Comment: Can you try  `Camera.Parameters.Camera.Parameters`?

Comment: thanks for your reply but  I tried and did not work.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that you have to use `startPreview` again in order to enable the flash. In an older project I did something like this to enable/disable flash:

```
Camera.Parameters params = camera.getParameters();
if (params.getFlashMode().equals(Camera.Parameters.FLASH_MODE_ON)) {
    params.setFlashMode(Camera.Parameters.FLASH_MODE_ON);
} else {
    params.setFlashMode(Camera.Parameters.FLASH_MODE_OFF);
}
camera.setParameters(params);
```

Also, you may want to open/close the camera with `AsyncTask` because it is a UI blocking operation.

Update: This is how your method should look

```
public void FlashOn() {
    Camera.Parameters params = cam.getParameters();
    params.setFlashMode(Camera.Parameters.FLASH_MODE_ON);
    cam.setParameters(params);
}
```

For `FlashOff` method, things will be similar.

Comment: Firstly very thanks. But your code  did not work and an error and gave an error. Error : 
Exception getMessage: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.hardware.Camera$Parameters android.hardware.Camera.getParameters()' on a null object reference

Comment: Well, this means the the `camera` object is null. Are you sure that you initialised it?

Comment: Yes, ı am sure. I can even switch between front and rear cameras.

Comment: In this case, can you update the question code to reflect the latest changes?

Comment: Do you have a button to enable/disable flash? Or how do you exactly do it?

Comment: So, I am using an application camera after I use front and back cameras. I want to turn the flash on and off in the dark when the camera is turned on. I tried many methods camera2 and different codes but I got many errors **The camera device is in use already** , **E/Camera: Error 2** but it didn't work.

As I mentioned in the title, how to open the flash without error when the camera is on because either the camera frezees flash is turned on or flash not turned on camera is still active.

Comment: Well, without having access to the full code I can't say what's wrong or not. I would say that you should check some tutorial and follow those steps and see what is different in your code.

Comment: Ok Iulian. Thank you so much.